# SOLR: Adding logical operators via filters

Tags: search, solr

Hi I don't know how to phrase this question so I'll try to have a go with an example.

Assume My Search Term is: `PHP/MYSQL`

And I have 6 documents in index with "raw" content being:

```
1: PHP MYSQL
2: PHP/MYSQL
3: PHP
4: MYSQL
5: PHP some stuff here and then MYSQL
6: weirdos may enter stuff like PHPMYSQL
```

what I expect this query to search for is `"PHP MYSQL" OR (PHP AND MYSQL)` bringing me documents 1,2(slashes are stripped in indexing time),5 and 6

I've tried solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory with various different options, I even tried to perform it manually on query analyzer with:

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="(\S+)[\.\\;,\/:!\?]+(\S+)"
                replacement="$1$2 || $1 &amp;&amp; $2"
                replace="all"
                />
```

I can't get solr to recognize my "&&"s or "||" at this stage.

Can anyone suggest a combination of filters to achieve this behavior?

SOLR version is 3.5

Comment: Should really document 6 be matched? The token there would be PHPMYSQL.

Comment: unfortunately yes. it is in the story definition

Comment: I might need to resort to "PHP MYSQL" OR PHP OR MYSQL which is easy to achieve with just WordDelimeterParser